# Opening projects in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have two projects in my project explorer in eclipse, next to one of them it says "in project 1" in parentheses. How do I get eclipse to go "in" to project 2?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: I fixed it already. thanks